# PHP Redirect to HTML page after submit

Tags: php, html, forms

I would like to have users fill out my contact form, hit submit and then be redirected to my success.html page that thanks them for their submission. Everything worked great when I did this on a local Apache server while I was developing my site. Now that I put it up on the web, hitting submit no longer redirects to the success.html page, instead it takes them straight back to index.php which I don't want. I tried using the php headers and I also tried using JS with window.location to redirect users as suggested in similar Stack Overflow questions but neither worked. Can someone help me here? Thank- you!

```
  <?php

if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    //errors array
    $errors = array();
    //message variables
    $name = $_POST['form-name'];
    $email = $_POST['form-email'];
    $message = 'This is a message from: ' . $name . '.' . "\r\n\r\n" . 'Please send your reply to: ' . $email . '. ' . "\r\n\r\n" . $_POST['form-msg'];
    $headers = 'From: ' . $email;


    //Validation for name, email, and message fields
    if (empty($name) === true || empty($email) === true || empty($message) === true) {
        $errors[] = 'Name, email, and message are required!';

    } else {
        if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
            $errors[] = 'That\'s not a valid email address.';
        }
        if (ctype_alpha(str_replace(' ', '', $name)) === false) {
            $errors[] = 'Name must only contain letters!';

    } 

}
   if (empty ($errors) === true) {
       //send email
       mail('myemail@gmail.com', 'Contact Form Submission', $message, $headers);
       //redirect user
       header('Location: http:/www.mysite.com/success.html');
       exit();
   }

 }


?>


                    <?php
        if (isset($_GET['sent']) === true) {
            header('Location: success.html');

        } else {
            if (empty($errors) === false) {
                echo '<ul>';
                foreach($errors as $error) {
                    echo '<li>', $error, '<li>';
                }
            }


            ?>

                        <form method='post' action='success.html'>
                            <label for='form-name'>Name: </label>
                            <input type='text' name='form-name' id='form-name' placeholder="Type your name..." required <?php if (isset($_POST[ 'form-name'])===true) { echo 'value="', strip_tags($_POST[ 'form-name']), '"';}?>>
                            <br>
                            <label for='form-email'>Email: </label>
                            <input type='email' name='form-email' id='form-email' placeholder="Type your email..." required <?php if (isset($_POST[ 'form-email'])===true) { echo 'value="', strip_tags($_POST[ 'form-email']), '"';}?>>
                            <br>
                            <label for='form-msg'>Msg: </label>
                            <textarea type='text' name='form-msg' id='form-msg' placeholder="You get the drift..." required <?php if (isset($_POST[ 'form-msg'])===true) { echo 'value="', strip_tags($_POST[ 'form-msg']), '"';}?>></textarea>
                            <br>
                            <input type='submit' value='Submit' id='submit-button'><br>
                        </form>


                        <?php
            }

            ?>
```

Comment: If this is your actual code, and not a hand-transcribed reproduction, you have a typo in your `header()` URL

Comment: In what way? Could you be more specific? I know very little about PHP other than using it for this contact form so sorry for my ignorance. Thanks!

Comment: Look here `http:/www.` See anything missing?

Comment: `http:/www.mysite.com` You're missing a second `/`.  It seems like modern browsers (at least my current Chrome version) give you some leniency and decipher it for you, but it is technically incorrect

Comment: thanks, yeah I see that now. I fixed it, and now it is redirecting as it should but the contact form email is no longer sending when I fill out the form.

Comment: It's rather unclear as to what flow of the code you've included is. Is that all in one file? Multiple files? What's the file name (or names)? I see multiple references to `.html` files, but no references to any `.php` files. How is your PHP code actually being run?

Comment: @JayBlanchard answer does not have to do with PHP at all. It has to do how an URL is structured. Your URL is wrong. The http part inside the `header()` function should be: `http://`

Comment: JayBlanchard --> It's all one file, an index.php file that is my main page. I only included the form and PHP code, not all the other HTML I have on the site. There is another file, success.html which I didn't include here because it just has the "Thanks for contacting me." text and a link back to the index. 
@JackGal I fixed that URL, now it's redirecting but the email isn't being sent to my inbox as it should upon pressing submit.

Comment: `<form method='post' action='success.html'>` That submits the form to success.html, not index.php

Comment: Patrick, so I just changed the form action to index.php which allows for the email to be sent again but now it isn't redirecting to the success.html page.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you obviously need to spend some time figuring out exactly what everything you've written actually does.  This is why most experience developers will advocate for the [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) (i.e. splitting PHP and HTML as much as possible). Do some debugging and see where you're going sideways, what code is actually being reached, and what the values of your variables are.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep working at it. I had everything working fine when it was on the local server. I'm not sure what effect hosting had, but thank you for the help!

Comment: @PatrickQ I figured it out. I moved the PHP code into a separate file submit.php and then set the action attribute to that page so the form submission would run through my PHP code. Then, I set the headers to redirect the user to my success.html page displaying "Thank you for your submission." That was the problem, not using a php page. If you can submit an answer, I would like to give you credit for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here.  The first is the one that is actually posed in the question.  The solution to this is changing `header('Location: http:/www.example.com/success.html');` to `header('Location: http://www.example.com/success.html');`  (I know that you actually had `mysite.com`, but we're not allowed to use that in answers.

The second issue is that the form is posting to an HTML page, when it should (almost certainly) be posting to a PHP page.  `<form method='post' action='success.html'>`.  Since you said that all of the code you provided was in index.php, I suggested `<form method='post' action='index.php'>`

That said, having all this code together in one file is quite hard to follow and tends to lead to confusion and errors.  Following the principle of [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), you should split your form-handling code out into a new file that simply decides what to do with the submitted data and acts appropriately.  Any HTML should be in its own file as much as possible.

If I had to guess, I'd say that this never actually worked 100% in your testing environment. Instead, the errors were probably just masked.